# Is it possible to remove NICs from a domain controller in DNS?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I have the following situation and I'm not sure what its implications are.

On a barebone server with 4 network interfaces, I'm running one of two DCs to my domain. Now, in spite of 4 network interfaces being available on this server, I only wish that one of them has any meaning with regards to the domain. But all interfaces are connected to the network and have a valid IP address.

I already made a couple of configurations. For one, I unchecked "Register connection in DNS" for the three interfaces. Also, in the server properties in the DNS manager, I set the property "Listen on only the following IP addresses" and unchecked the ones that should not listen.

Now, in spite of me doing all that, these addresses still keep popping back up in the domain's DomainDnsZones and ForestDnsZones. I can delete them but they just keep coming back. So, when running `nslookup mydomain.com`, it will show these 3 IP addresses as well.

1. I tried so many things but failed. Is there anything I can do, apart from disabling the network interfaces entirely, to have them not play a role in the domain?
2. Am I approaching this maybe in a wrong way? Is there even a reason I should be even worried that those additional IP addresses are present?

Comment: Why are they even configured and connected, when you dont want them? Is NIC Teaming an option for you?

Comment: Multihoming a Domain Controller is *bad*. That said, if you set all interfaces to not register in DNS *and* set the DNS service to not listen on them, this *should* work...

Comment: @Virsacer the three interfaces are actually each bound to a hyper v switch. I'm not 100% sure but wouldn't the switch lose connection if I disabled them in the host system?

Comment: @Massimo yes, that's the case

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the PublishAddresses registry value

Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters
Value: PublishAddresses

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/a-record-registered-host-dns

Comment: Isn't this the same as removing the IP address from the DNS server manager, also mentioned in the linked article under _method 2_?